# How to adjust section margin after transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that transitions on the Y-axis by 100px. I am wanting my blue div `#home-section3` to not have any top margin from `.home-section2` after the transition, but ideally I do not want to have to set the margin-top to `-100px` for every div below the transition div. Is there a different way in which I can get the white-space gap to not appear after the transition finishes?

[Here is a fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/ukfdLar8/)

```js
function section2Delays() {
  $('.home-section2').addClass('fadeDisplay');
};
setTimeout(section2Delays, 300);
```

```css
.home-section2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  background: green;
}

.home-section2.fadeDisplay {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

#home-section3 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #094765;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home-section2"></div>
<section id="home-section3"></section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `margin-bottom:-100px` in class `.fadeDisplay`

```js
function section2Delays() {
  $('.home-section2').addClass('fadeDisplay');
};
setTimeout(section2Delays, 300);
```

```css
.home-section2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin-top: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  background: green;
}

.home-section2.fadeDisplay {
  transform: translateY(-100px);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-100px);
  transition: 1s;
  -webkit-transition: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
  margin:0 0 -100px 0 ;
}

#home-section3 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background: #094765;
  padding: 50px 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="home-section2"></div>
<section id="home-section3"></section>
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't even think of this method. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use `margin-top` instead of `transform`.

```
.fadeDisplay {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ugxbnkcc/)**

In fact, the whole animation can be done with CSS only.

```
.home-section2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  animation: ani 2s forwards;
}

@keyframes ani {
  to {
    margin-top: 0;
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

**[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/db07obhb/)**